# Does ESP32-WROVER-E module support the PDM interface?

Tags: esp32

Does the ESP32-WROVER-E module support the PDM interface? I'm trying to interface PDM microphones for one of the project requirements.
Has anybody tried to interface with PDM microphones to the mentioned module?

Below are the part number and links for the same.

- IM72D128V01
- IM69D130V11

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IM72D128-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c80027ecd0180612a60277e10

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IM69D130-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462602a9dc801607a0e46511a2e

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As I understand the datasheet, the I2S module is capable of decoding PDM signals.

Comment: Thanks Jens for your reply, 
but in the datasheet, I didn't see anywhere they are mentioning PDM interface if Im not wrong.

Comment: Please provide specific model and link to datasheet of PDM microphone(s) you are asking about.

Comment: Short answer, no. PDM requires very high frequency sampling or recording of 1-bit data. You need to provide a clock signal to a PDM microphone and record bits at the same speed if you go direct route. Another way is to average/filter the 1-bit stream, use a codec IC in between and then send data to ESP32 as PCM.

Comment: Your question has remained open for 12 days, flagged for insufficient details in the question, and you haven't fixed the problem by at least providing the model and datasheet for the PDM. That's why it is closed now.

Comment: The interface description is here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/i2s.html

Comment: Hi Edin, 

Below are the part number and links for the same.

IM72D128V01
IM69D130V11
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IM72D128-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=8ac78c8c80027ecd0180612a60277e10

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IM69D130-DS-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462602a9dc801607a0e46511a2e